# Which one to buy Tableau or Power BI for my given scenarios?

Tags: tableau-api, powerbi

Thanks for taking time and looking into my query. I have below scenarios and would require your help on suggesting a good BI tool.

Scenario:

1. We are organization of 500 employees
2. There will be 10 designers out of 500 who will be designing the dashboard using BI desktop tool
3. We are going to connect oracle 12c database as a Data Mart
4. We need a server for publishing the dashboard
5. All 500 employees need view access to the dashboard
6. All 500 employee may view the dashboard either in windows, Mac, IPhone or Android device
7. Around 100 will be frequent visitor, almost every day.
8. Designer may integrate/embed our dashboard to other applications for analysis
9. We have our own internal server and we don’t want to use cloud
10. We don’t want anybody to download anything on their system , just by click of web link they should be able to see the dashboard
11. The data size for analysis will be around 150GB and its growing every month on month

Can someone please let me know, what are my options in Tableau and Power BI for above requirements?

As per the tableau website its $xx for desktop and $yy for tableau server, Can I add all 500 people for viewing the dashboard?

Power BI desktop is free, but Power BI pro is $y.yy.

Is power BI pro features equal to Tableau server feature for all my above scenarios? Or does it vary based on number of user accessing the server?

Comment: This isn't the proper site to ask this sort of question nor is your question specific enough to generate good answers.

Comment: You'll also need [Power BI Premium](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi-premium/) on top of Power BI Pro for your case.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a technical question and thus it's a bit hard to answer.

Choosing of a BI solution is something you should do after doing a lot of research for yourself. The information you've provided is hardly enough to make a decision.

Since you are the one who knows intensively what your data looks like, what kinds of analysis and dashboards you want to do and all the nitty gritties. I'd advice you to download trial versions for all the BI softwares that sparked your interest and try to do some end to end work with them.

That is the only conclusive way to decide.

Answer (score 0):

I am in a similar situation as the opening question.

I am currently considering 'Grafana'

https://github.com/grafana/grafana

An operational live version can be tested here

https://play.grafana.org/

Not sure if is a viable replacement if you need Tableau, but it likely is enough in many situations